# Unexpected crashing of WP7 app. RootFrame_NavigationFailed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have WP7 app that has a List page with 8 textblocks that each navigate to a new page.  While testing on the emulator and phone I can hit any textblock over and over with no issues, but if I go down the list of items in order from top to bottom(or reverse) I will eventually hit one that will stop at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); with app.rootframe_navigationfailed .  I can run it again and hit that same textblock with no exception?  Is this a bug?  Has anyone ever run into this before?

```
// Code to execute if a navigation fails
    private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Call Stack:(don't how to make this image easier to read)
[image]

xaml:

```
Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,-5,6,0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrolViewer" >
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Height="Auto" Margin="6,5,0,0" Name="Bombay" Text="BOMBAY"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="56" ManipulationStarted="Bombay_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Click event:

```
private void Bombay_Click(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Bombay.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        args.Complete();
        args.Handled = true;
    }
```

EDIT:
I've also tried tap event and issue still persists.

```
private void bombay_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Bombay.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        //stop the event from going to the parent map control
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); of App.xaml.cs.  I just created a test app with 8 textblocks on main page that each navigate to new page.  I click it, then back button and then another textblock.  No issues.  I wonder if its somehow the size of content(images, text) from the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Bombay.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

should be

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Bombay.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Still crashes.  This has got to be a bug.

Comment: @KFP I doubt it. Navigation is a pretty simple, straight foreword thing. I think I do it in almost every single app I've published.

Comment: I know...so far that's why this has been so baffling.  But after further testing I believe it has something to do with the content in my page..the text and images.  I created a new project and added the textblocks(which were empty) and it ran fine.  Then i added the content of a few of my pages(text, images) and it crashes. is there a limit on image size?